# Accessing JSON values jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have JSON being returned like so:

```
{
    "response": {
        "2012-07-01": {
            "Variations": [
                {
                    "ID": 293,
                    "InternalItemID": "xyz",
                    "RRP": "50.00",
                    "Price": "40.00",
                    "Available": 65,
                    "RedeemableDate": "2012-07-01"
                },
                {
                    "ID": 107,
                    "InternalItemID": "xxx",
                    "RRP": "50.00",
                    "Price": "10.00",
                    "Available": 15,
                    "RedeemableDate": "2012-07-01"
                },
                {
                    "ID": 200,
                    "InternalItemID": "Item name",
                    "RRP": "50.00",
                    "Price": "40.00",
                    "Available": 65,
                    "RedeemableDate": "2012-07-01"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I need to cycle through it and access the various values.

I am currently trying to do this like so:

```
var calevents = [];
$.each(data.response, function(index,item){
    calDate = index;
    child = item.Variations;
    if ($.isEmptyObject(child) == false){
        calPrice = child[0].Price;
        calID = child[0].ID;
        calAvailable = child[0].Available;
        calevents.push({
            'id': calID,
            'title': buildEventTitle(calAvailable,
                    calDate.substring(calDate.length,calDate.length-2),
                    child[0].Price, calID, child[0].RRP),
            'start': $.fullCalendar.parseDate(calDate),
            'end': $.fullCalendar.parseDate(calDate),
            'allDay': true
        });
    }
});
```

but am getting child[0] is not defined errors.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: try to console.log(child) to see what element you're actually getting.

Comment: Thanks. I have done this and I just get back: []

Comment: 1) It's JSON, not jSON. 2) Always use `var` before variable declarations, unless you really want a global variable. 3) For a majority of cases you don't need to use `== true`, `== false` comparisons: Just use `if (!$.isEmptyObject(child))`. 4) You don't need to quote object literal properties names that are simple identifiers: Just use `id: calID` etc.

Comment: alright, this means that item doesn't have a Variations property, now take a step back and console.log(item), i'm beginning to feel you should use $(this) instead of item

Comment: It seems to be erroring when it receives a result like so: {"response": { "2012-06-01": { "Variations": [] } }}. Which I would hope would be picked up by !$.isEmptyObject(child) but it apparently seems to be evading this

Comment: Perhaps because Variations is an array, and not an object?
try `if (child.length > 0 ){` right below `child = item.Variations;`